# Having trouble fitting data to HMM-Learn model (Python3.9)

Tags: python, pandas, finance, quantitative-finance, hmmlearn

I am trying to model a Hidden Markov model to some stock data from the S&P500.

The data is downloaded from Yahoo Finance and is contained in a CSV-file containing the data for 250 trading days. I had this code working a week ago but now it does not seem to work.

```
import pandas as pd
from hmmlearn import hmm
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm, pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import YearLocator, MonthLocator

df = pd.read_csv( "SnP500_1Yhist.csv",
                   header      = 0,
                   index_col   = "Date",
                   parse_dates = True
                   )
df["Returns"] = df["Adj Close"].pct_change()
df.dropna( inplace = True )

hmm_model = hmm.GaussianHMM( n_components    =   4,
                             covariance_type =   "full",
                             n_iter          = 100
                             )               # %Create the model
df = df["Returns"]                           # %Extract the wanted column of data
training_set = np.column_stack( df )         # %Shape = [1,250]

hmm_model.fit( training_set )                # %This is where I get the error
```

The error I get is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-c8f66806fad6> in <module>
      9 print(training_set.shape)
     10 print(training_set)
---> 11 hmm_model.fit(training_set)

~/Git Projects/Aiguille Systems/allocationmodel/macromodelv2_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hmmlearn/base.py in fit(self, X, lengths)
    460         """
    461         X = check_array(X)
--> 462         self._init(X, lengths=lengths)
    463         self._check()
    464 

~/Git Projects/Aiguille Systems/allocationmodel/macromodelv2_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hmmlearn/hmm.py in _init(self, X, lengths)
    205             kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=self.n_components,
    206                                     random_state=self.random_state)
--> 207             kmeans.fit(X)
    208             self.means_ = kmeans.cluster_centers_
    209         if self._needs_init("c", "covars_"):

~/Git Projects/Aiguille Systems/allocationmodel/macromodelv2_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/_kmeans.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1033                                 accept_large_sparse=False)
   1034 
-> 1035         self._check_params(X)
   1036         random_state = check_random_state(self.random_state)
   1037 

~/Git Projects/Aiguille Systems/allocationmodel/macromodelv2_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/_kmeans.py in _check_params(self, X)
    956         # n_clusters
    957         if X.shape[0] < self.n_clusters:
--> 958             raise ValueError(f"n_samples={X.shape[0]} should be >= "
    959                              f"n_clusters={self.n_clusters}.")
    960 

ValueError: n_samples=1 should be >= n_clusters=4.
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"...it does not seem to work."*

Well,
it does. If you test your actual `training_set` prior to call the `.fit()` method, which we cannot reproduce here, you will get a straight reason why the error was reported:

```
N_COMPONENTS = 4
ERR_MASK     = ( "ERR: training_set was smaller than the N_COMPONENTS == {0:}"
               + "requested,\n"
               + "     whereas the actual shape[0] was {1:}"
                  )
...

hmm_model = hmm.GaussianHMM( n_components    =   N_COMPONENTS,
                             covariance_type =   "full",
                             n_iter          = 100
                             )
...

( hmm_model.fit( training_set )    if training_set.shape[0] >= N_COMPONENTS
                                 else print( ERR_MASK.format(  N_COMPONENTS,
                                                               training_set.shape[0]
                                                               )
                                             )
  )
```

```
~/Git Projects/Aiguille Systems/allocationmodel/macromodelv2_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/_kmeans.py in _check_params(self, X)
    956         # n_clusters
    957         if X.shape[0] < self.n_clusters:
--> 958             raise ValueError(f"n_samples={X.shape[0]} should be >= "
    959                              f"n_clusters={self.n_clusters}.")
--------------------------------------------------X.shape[0]------------
--------------------------------------------------X.shape[0]------------

ValueError: n_samples=1 should be >= n_clusters=4.
```

---

```
fit( X, lengths = None )

    Estimate model parameters.

    An initialization step is performed before entering the EM algorithm.
       If you want to avoid this step for a subset of the parameters,
       pass proper init_params keyword argument to estimator’s constructor.

    Parameters

            X ( array-like, shape ( n_samples, n_features ) )
              – Feature matrix of individual samples.

            lengths ( array-like of integers, shape ( n_sequences, ) )
              – Lengths of the individual sequences in X.
                The sum of these should be n_samples.
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I have tested the array and have tried both dimensions [250, 1] as well as [1, 250], neither work.

Comment: The Traceback is clear: ***"`ValueError: n_samples=1 should be >= n_clusters=4.`"*** You try to serve data into the `.fit()`-method, that is not compatible with the documented and published API.